# SolrJ querying to compute statistics based on field facets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, solr, lucene

I am trying to compute statistics for a field based on a facet. My browser query is as follows:

```
select?q=<someFilterQuery>&rows=100&wt=json&indent=true&stats=true&stats.field=<statsField>&stats.facet=<statsFacetField>
```

The above query works just fine and gives the desired result. However, when I try to use SolrJ in the following way:

```
val query = new SolrQuery()
query.setQuery("/select")
query.set("q","<FilterQuery>")
query.setGetFieldStatistics("<statsField>")
query.addStatsFieldFacets("<statsFacetField>")
val response = solrclient.query(query)
println(response.getFieldStatsInto().size())
```

I just "1" as the output instead of getting the number of facets.

I am having a hard time understanding the SolrJ documentation as many funtions have not been described at all. Is there any way to run a browser query directly through SolrJ instead of having to add individual parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the below to enable stats

`query.setGetFieldStatistics(true);`